# Error: Unknown constructor 'StandardPaginationSorting.StandardPaginationSorting(ApexPages.StandardController controller)'

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, error, controller-extension, standardcontroller

to all I am trying to provide the sorting and pagination on standard controller with extension by followingly,**My controller**

```
public class StandardPaginationSorting {

    // Variables required for Sorting.
    public String soql {get;set;}
    public List <Account> CandidateList1 = New List <Account>();
    public String soqlsort {get;set;}
    public List <Account> CandidateList2 = New List <Account>();

                // List used in to display the table in VF page.
                public List<Account> getCandidateList() {
                    // Passing the values of list to VF page.
                    return con.getRecords();
                }

                // instantiate the StandardSetController from a query locator
                public ApexPages.StandardSetController con {
                    get {
                                                if(con == null) {
                                                                // String Query to have a list of cases for a respective End-user.
                                                                soql = 'SELECT Name, Email, Website,BillingCountry, Phone, Type, Owner.Name FROM Account';

                                                                // Passing the String array to a list with Selected field sorting.
                                                                CandidateList1 = Database.query(soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir ); 

                                                                // setting values of List in StandardSetController.
                                                                con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(CandidateList1);

                                                                // sets the number of records in each page set
                                                                con.setPageSize(5);
                                                }
                                                return con;
        }
        set;
    }

    // indicates whether there are more records after the current page set.
    public Boolean hasNext {
        get {
            return con.getHasNext();
        }
        set;
    }

    // indicates whether there are more records before the current page set.
    public Boolean hasPrevious {
        get {
            return con.getHasPrevious();
        }
        set;
    }

    // returns the page number of the current page set
    public Integer pageNumber {
        get {
            return con.getPageNumber();
        }
        set;
    }

    // returns the first page of records
    public void first() {
        con.first();
    }

    // returns the last page of records
    public void last() {
        con.last();
    }

    // returns the previous page of records
    public void previous() {
        con.previous();
    }

    // returns the next page of records
    public void next() {
        con.next();
    }

    // returns the PageReference of the original page, if known, or the home page.
    public void cancel() {
        con.cancel();
    }

    // Method for Constructor is used for Test Class.
    public StandardPaginationSorting(){
    }

   //Toggles the sorting of query from asc<-->desc
    public void toggleSort() {
        // simply toggle the direction
        sortDir = sortDir.equals('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';

                                // run the query again for sorting other columns
                                soqlsort = 'SELECT Name, Email, Phone, BillingCountry, Website, Owner.Name, Type FROM Account'; 

                                // Adding String array to a List array
                                CandidateList2 = Database.query(soqlsort + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir ); 

                                // Adding Caselist to Standard Pagination controller variable
                                con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(CandidateList2);

                                // Set Page Size to 5
                                con.setPageSize(5);

    }

    // the current sort direction. defaults to asc
    public String sortDir {
        // To set a Direction either in ascending order or descending order.
                                get  { if (sortDir == null) {  sortDir = 'asc'; } return sortDir;}
        set;
    }

    // the current field to sort by. defaults to last name
    public String sortField {
        // To set a Field for sorting.
                                get  { if (sortField == null) {sortField = 'Name'; } return sortField;  }
        set;
    } 

}
```

and **My Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="StandardPaginationSorting" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"> 

    <!-- CSS added to display alternate row colors and Center align Text in PageblockTable -->
    <style type="text/css">
        .oddrow{background-color: #00FFFF; } 
        .evenrow{background-color: #7FFFD4; } 
        .textalign{text-align:center; } 
    </style>

    <apex:form id="form">
        <!-- Tabstyle attribute is used to assign the color scheme to the pageblock.Here Candidate Object color scheme is used for the pageblock-->
        <apex:pageBlock id="pgblock" tabStyle="Account">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Candidate Details -  Page #{!pageNumber}" columns="1" collapsible="false">   
                <!-- Rowclasses attribute is used to define different CSS classes for different rows. 
                     Rules attribute is used: borders drawn between cells in the page block table.
                     Title attribute will be used as a help text when a user hovers mouse over the Page Block table.
                     Styleclass, HeaderClass attributes are used to Center align Table Text in Page Block table --->
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CandidateList}" var="CadList" rowClasses="oddrow,evenrow"   rules="groups"  title="Click Column Header for Sorting"  styleclass="textalign" headerClass="textalign" >
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                           <apex:commandLink value="Name" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="pgblock">
                                <!-- Value attribute should have field (API Name) to sort in asc or desc order -->
                                <apex:param name="sortField" value="Name" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                           </apex:commandLink>
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!CadList.Name}"/>
                    </apex:column> 

                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            <apex:commandLink value="Phone" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="pgblock">
                                <apex:param name="sortField" value="Phone" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                            </apex:commandLink>
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!CadList.Phone}"/>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            <apex:commandLink value="Email" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="pgblock">
                                <apex:param name="sortField" value="Email" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                            </apex:commandLink>
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!CadList.Email}"/>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            <apex:commandLink value="Type" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="pgblock">
                                <apex:param name="sortField" value="Type" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                            </apex:commandLink>
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!CadList.Type}"/>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            <apex:commandLink value="Owner.Name" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="pgblock">
                                <apex:param name="sortField" value="Owner.Name" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                            </apex:commandLink>
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!CadList.Owner.Name}"/>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            <apex:commandLink value="Website" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="pgblock">
                                <apex:param name="sortField" value="Website" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                            </apex:commandLink>
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!CadList.Website}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:panelGrid columns="4">
                <apex:commandLink action="{!first}">First</apex:commandlink>
                <apex:commandLink action="{!previous}" rendered="{!hasPrevious}">Previous</apex:commandlink>
                <apex:commandLink action="{!next}" rendered="{!hasNext}">Next</apex:commandlink>
                <apex:commandLink action="{!last}">Last</apex:commandlink>
            </apex:panelGrid>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

But Unfortuntely I get the following error

> Error: Unknown constructor
>   'StandardPaginationSorting.StandardPaginationSorting(ApexPages.StandardController
>   controller)'

during saving time of my visual page So Can you please give the solution to remove the error and get the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Constructor that includes a `ApexPages.StandardController` parameter.

i.e.

```
public StandardPaginationSorting(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
}
```